# How can I plot this solution curves of this differential equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I have this home work problem:
[image]

How can I plot the solution curves without having the missing values of C, R? I tried solving it using the characteristic equation but it did not yeild anything meaningful to me.

I would like to put some closure to this question. Anxiety got the better of me and I didn't fully read/understand the whole question but as the comment suggests the question is specifically asking to see how the solution varies as those parameters vary so I used Mathematica with the manipulate function to create this graph

[image]

Using this Mathematica function, courtesy of @Nasser

```
Manipulate[
 sol = q[t] /. 
   First@DSolve[{r q'[t] + q[t]/c == v, q[0] == ic}, q[t], t];
 Grid[{{sol},
   {Plot[sol, {t, 0, maxT}, PlotRange -> {{0, maxT}, {0, maxQ}}, 
     ImagePadding -> 40, ImageSize -> 300, Frame -> True, 
     FrameLabel -> {{"q(t)", None}, {"t", "Solution to the problem"}},
      GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
     PlotStyle -> Red]
    }}],

 {{c, 1.6, "c"}, 0, 2, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny},
 {{r, .1, "r"}, .1, 2, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny},
 {{v, 1.5, "c"}, .1, 2, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny},
 {{ic, 1, "q[0]"}, 0, 2, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny},
 {{maxT, 1, "time scale"}, 1, 100, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny},
 {{maxQ, 3, "y scale"}, .1, 10, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny}
 ]
```

Comment: The values of that quantities are exactly $R,C,V$. So is, it's implicitly stated that these values are known, although unspecified, constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first option is to choose arbitrary values of the parameters, "hoping" that they will be representative and general enough.

Another is to get rid of the constants by using reduced variables. You can do that at the equation level or the solution level.

The equation reads

$$R\frac{dQ(t)}{dt}+\frac1CQ(t)=V.$$

We can change the scale of time by setting $t:=RCu$ and get

$$\frac R{RC}\frac{dQ(u)}{du}+\frac1CQ(u)=V,$$ or

$$\frac{dQ(u)}{dt}+Q(u)=VC.$$

Then we can rescale the charge by setting

$$q(u):=\frac{Q(u)}{VC}$$ and get the reduced equation

$$\color{green}{q'(u)+q(u)=1}.$$

Any solution of the original equation can be obtained by stretching the solutions of the reduced equation in time and in charge.

---

When you consider the RHS with an extra parameter, the method seems to break down. Anyway, you can split the RHS in two and handle separately the terms in $V_0$ (as above) and in $b$.

This will yield a new reduced equation

$$\color{green}{q'(u)+q(u)=u}.$$

The solution of the original equation will be a linear combination of the solutions of the above two reduced equations, stretched in time.

The case of

$$\frac{bt}{t+1}$$ won't work as easily, because if you change the scale of time, a constant reappears at the denominator.